# Angular does not re-render html component after calling API

Tags: angular, typescript

Code of my *product-list* component is as follows:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ProductsListService} from './products-list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-list',
  templateUrl: './products-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductsListComponent {
  rerender = false;
  products;
  constructor(private service: ProductsListService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.products = service.getProducts();
  }
  getProductsAgain(query: string): void {
    this.products = this.service.getProducts(query);
    console.log(this.products);
    this.doRerender();
  }
  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  doRerender() {
    this.rerender = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.rerender = false;
  }
}
```

and html looks like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!rerender">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products">
      <img src="{{product.picture}}" height="150px">
      <p>{{product.title}}</p>
      <div>
        <p>{{"ENERC_KCAL: "+product.nutrients._ENERC_KCAL}}</p>
        <p>{{"PROCNT: "+product.nutrients._PROCNT}}</p>
        <p>{{"FAT: "+product.nutrients._FAT}}</p>
        <p>{{"CHOCDF: "+product.nutrients._CHOCDF}}</p>
        <p>{{"FIBTG: "+product.nutrients._FIBTG}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

also *product-list.service* looks like this:

```
import {Injectable, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ResponseDTO} from './ResponseDTO';
import {NutrientsDTO} from './NutrientsDTO';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsListService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getProducts(q?: string): Array<ResponseDTO> {
    const query = (q === undefined) || (q == null) || (q === '') || (q === ' ') ? 'orange' : q;
    const url = 'https://edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com/parser?ingr=' + query;
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-rapidapi-key': '9f95da4cd3mshd0fbea030c7c8e3p16d06bjsn503efa8f187f',
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com'
    });
    const arr: Array<any> = [];
    const res: Array<ResponseDTO> = [];
    this.http.get(url, {headers: httpHeaders, observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'}).subscribe(data => {
        const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        arr.push(obj.hints);
        for (const ar of arr) {
          const nutrients: NutrientsDTO = new NutrientsDTO();
          for (const a of ar) {
            // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
            for (const nutrient in a.food.nutrients) {
              if (a.food.nutrients.hasOwnProperty(nutrient)) {
                if (nutrient === 'ENERC_KCAL') {
                  nutrients.ENERC_KCAL = Math.round((a.food.nutrients[nutrient] + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                } else if (nutrient === 'PROCNT') {
                  nutrients.PROCNT = Math.round((a.food.nutrients[nutrient] + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                } else if (nutrient === 'FAT') {
                  nutrients.FAT = Math.round((a.food.nutrients[nutrient] + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                } else if (nutrient === 'CHOCDF') {
                  nutrients.CHOCDF = Math.round((a.food.nutrients[nutrient] + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                } else if (nutrient === 'FIBTG') {
                  nutrients.FIBTG = Math.round((a.food.nutrients[nutrient] + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                } else {
                  console.log('not found!');
                }
              }
            }
            const noImgUrl = 'https://st4.depositphotos.com/14953852/24787/v/600/depositphotos_247872612-stock-illustration-no-image-available-icon-vector.jpg';
            const imgSrc = a.food.image == null ? noImgUrl : a.food.image;
            const response: ResponseDTO = new ResponseDTO(imgSrc, a.food.category, a.food.label, nutrients);
            res.push(response);
          }
        }
      }
    );
    return res;
  }
}
```

I am calling *product-list* method *getProductsAgain* by different component *search-bar*, which simply goes back to the service and calls API again with given parameter. The call is successful and it also assigns value to product variable of *ProductsListComponent*, but page does not refresh or re-render html. What should I do? or what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE #1:**

Still have same problem, I tried all methods like `trackBy`, `[...arrayOfResults]`, returned Subscription or Observable in component and got result in there, inspected result with `setTimeout(()=>{console.log(products)},5000);` to see if API request really assigns new values to products variable (and it does!). I even tried to force re-render with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` but no success.
So with API request is nothing wrong, but for some reason angular does not see that I update with API request products variable and its stuck on initial results (results in `service.getProducts()`). What am I doing so wrong?

Comment: Your constructor should almost always be empty. You should use `ngOnInit()` instead.

Comment: You need to show us what `service.getProducts()` looks like. It might be returning the wrong thing.

Comment: it returns `Array<ResponseDTO>` array list of object where I map JSON response values to object variables. I will update question with more info

Comment: Your code returns the array before the http request even finishes, thus your function is returning an empty array. Use a subscription and return the subscription.

Comment: but how come when I `console.log(this.products)` after API call i do get all necessary data?

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this as follow ?; i didnt try it but it is might be all right.

```
getProductsAgain(query: string): void {
    this.service.getProductsAgain(query).subscribe(response => {
        this.products = response.data;
        console.log(this.products);
        this.doRerender();
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Comment: It failed to compile because I cannot subscribe to non observable array.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it has to do with the fact that arrays and objects in JavaScript are reference types and you have to change the location of RAM for these type of variables for change detection to take place.

Try this:

```
getProductsAgain(query: string): void {
    // assign this.products to a new location in RAM/memory for change detection to take place
    // by using the spread operator and assigning to a new array
    this.products = [...this.service.getProducts(query)];
    // console.log(this.products); I don't think you need these two lines anymore
    // this.doRerender();
  }
```